# Allow only alphabets and special characters

Tags: regex

I want an input field to allow only alphabets and special characters. Can someone specify it

```
/[ A-Za-z@]/i
```

Comment: /^[A-Z@~`!@#$%^*()_=+\\\';:\/?>.,-]/i this works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
/^[A-Z@~`!@#$%^&*()_=+\\\\';:\"\\/?>.<,-]*$/i
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vA1gB8/1).

Due to `/i` modifier, you do not have to specify `a-z` range in the character class as case-insensitivity is enabled.

The regex matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `` [A-Z@~`!@#$%^&*()_=+\\\\';:\"\\/?>.<,-]* `` - 0 or more characters inside the `A-Za-z` range and all the special ASCII characters (you can add more if I missed any or if you need to support more)
- `$` - end of string.